# Is it a good idea to put srand() in the header file?

Tags: c, header-files, srand

My program includes a function that uses `rand()`. That function will be called more than once so I can't put `srand()` at the beginning of the function. Now, is there a general rule that suggests whether `srand()` should be put in the header file of the function, or in the beginning of the main function?

My understanding is that both would work the same. The only difference is that if I want to reuse the function in the future, having `srand()` in the header makes the function more self-contained, but I may end up with multiple headers all having `srand()`.

--Edit--

Yes, I mean something like

```
/*header.h*/
srand();
void my_funciton();
```

So it won't work?

Comment: header files shouldn't contain executable code. just function definitions.

Comment: What happens if you want to do some testing with a predictable set of random numbers? Putting `srand()` in the header will make that impossible.

Comment: What do you meän by "putting srand to header file"? Can you add code snippet showing relevant part if the header?

Comment: @MarcB Executable code in headers is not necessarily bad. There's even C keyword `inline` for having function definitions (and not just declarations, which I assume you mean) in header files.

Comment: @hyde - but the code in the header won't be *executed* by simple virtue of being `#include`d; I think that's what the OP is hoping for.

Comment: @JohnBode Yeah, that's why I asked for clarification. So the issue is clear now and you answered it nicely.

Comment: "*So it won't work?*" why didn't you simply tried this? *sigh*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, is there a general rule that suggests whether srand() should be put in the header file of the function

If you mean something like

```
/**
 * foo.h
 */
 srand();

 void my_function_that_uses_rand();
```

that won't cause `srand` to be *called* by whatever includes the header file; it will be treated as an old-style implicit `int` function *declaration* (which will not work with C99 or later compilers, since implicit `int` function declarations are no longer supported), which will cause other problems if you've included `math.h` in whatever file is also including this file.

**EDIT**

Actually, it's worse than that, because a *call* to `srand` requires the seed parameter, so if you wanted to randomize on time, your header file would look something like

```
/**
 * foo.h
 */
srand(time(NULL));

void my_function_that_uses_rand();
```

which the compiler would immediately yak on, since `srand(time(NULL));` is not a valid declaration in the first place.

`srand` should be called once before the first call to `rand`, and it's up to the application code to do so.  Note that if you always call `srand` with the same seed value, you will always get the same sequence of values in your `rand` calls.

Answer (score 4):

In general, libraries should never call `srand`. The call to `srand` should be made once, usually in `main`, and is the responsibility of the application.

Any other solution ends up with multiple libraries competing with each other.

An application which uses a library which involves random numbers should seed the random number generator in whatever way seems appropriate for the application (something else which libraries don't know: what if the application needs to be reproducible, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Headers are intended to be reusable.  If your header is used in more than one source file, srand would be redundantly executed again at unexpected times.  Put it in main() or wherever, and call it just once.

Comment: "*srand would be redundantly executed*" it wouldn't, as the code wouldn't even compile a free standing call to a function.

Comment: There are ways to wrap it.

Comment: Even if it *is* wrapped it won't automagically get called every time the header gets included.

Comment: The guy is assumed to be making a positive effort to execute during inclusion.  `static int dummy = srand(...), 0;` would work, I think.  Why else ask the question?

Comment: For the `... = srand()` it wouldn't, at least not in C. And sry, but that's exactly why I downvoted your answer, as you seem to be guessing.